# RegExp to convert inverse trigonometric funcion (e.g. sin^(-1)(x)) to proper notaion (e.g. asin(x))

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
sin^(-1)(x)*cos^(-1)(x)
```

I want to transfrom it into:

```
asin(x)*acos(x)
```

How can I do this with javascript RegExp, considering symbol `^` in RegExp is special?

Comment: Escape the ^ character and the parentheses `\^\(1\)`.

Comment: This feel like a job more suited for librairies like [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/), than for regex.

Comment: give an example. How I can using mathjs transform `sin^(-1)(x)*cos^(-1)(x)` to `asin(x)*acos(x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If turning inverse trigonometric functions to their *proper* notation is what's required, you may go like that:

```js
const str = `sin^(-1)(x)*cos^(-1)(x)/tan^(-1)(x^3)*ctg^(-1)(x^2)`,
      functions = ['sin', 'cos', 'tan', 'ctg'],
      regExp = new RegExp(`(${functions.join('|')})\\^\\(-1\\)`, 'g')
      
      result = str.replace(regExp, "a$1")
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: I think you slould add to your answer more functions 
`result = str.replace(/(sin|cos|tan|ctg|cot|sec|csc|cosh|sinh|tanh|sech|csch|coth)\^\(-1\)/g, "a$1")
 `

Comment: @ДанилЧеркашин : I have modified my answer so that it is easier to scale to whatever extent is required (including secant, cosecant, hyperbolic funcions, like 'cosh', whatever)